# why doesnt my code retrieve values from my database?

Tags: java, sql

i have already created a user class and have established a connection with my databse but edited it out as it contains my private details.

```
  public ArrayList<User> ListUsers(String ValToSearch)
     {
    ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT ID, room_Type, host_Name, Neighbourhood WHERE ID=? AND room_Type=? AND host_Name=? AND Neighbourhood=? ) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);

        User user;

        while(rs.next())
        {
            user = new User(
                             rs.getInt("id"),
                             rs.getString("hname"),
                             rs.getString("rtype"),
                             rs.getString("area")
                            );
            usersList.add(user);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return usersList;
}

// function to display data in jtable
```

Comment: Your select statement is invalid. It's missing a `FROM` clause

Comment: add FROM but didnt work

Answer (score 3):

You are not:

- Using a PreparedStatement
- Using query to create PreparedStatement
- Setting parameters to your query
- Using `LIKE` operator properly

I would recommend having a look at [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) and a [PreparedStatement example](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/).